# Can I specify dependencies in mypy.ini?

Tags: python, mypy, pre-commit.com

We run mypy as part of [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/). Here is the portion of `.pre-commit-config.yaml` that refers to mypy

```yaml
    rev: v0.910
    # https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy/issues/5
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        name: mypy module1
        files: ^path/to.module1
      - id: mypy
        name: mypy module2
        files: ^path/to.module2
```

I recently made a change to a file being tested by one of those hooks and pre-commit failed with:

```
path/to/module/main.py:9: error: Library stubs not installed for "requests" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)
path/to/module/main:9: note: Hint: "python3 -m pip install types-requests"
path/to/module/main:9: note: (or run "mypy --install-types" to install all missing stub packages)
path/to/module/main:9: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
path/to/module/main:14: error: Library stubs not installed for "requests.models" (or incompatible with Python 3.9)
```

I fixed this by specifying types-requests as an additional dependency in `.pre-commit-config.yaml` so it now looks like this:

```yaml
    rev: v0.910
    # https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy/issues/5
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        additional_dependencies: [types-requests]
        name: mypy module1
        files: ^path/to.module1
      - id: mypy
        additional_dependencies: [types-requests]
        name: mypy module2
        files: ^path/to.module2
```

Someone else on my team suggested adding this to mypy.ini because we also run mypy in our CI pipeline so it would make sense if pre-commit and the CI pipeline were both using the same mypy.ini. I've been reading https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html but it doesn't (AFAICT) cover anything pertaining to defining additional dependencies.

I tried reverting my change to `.pre-commit-config.yaml` and instead placing file `mypy.ini` at the root of my repo containing:

```
[mypy]
additional_dependencies = [types-requests]
```

but upon running pre-commit again I got the same errors as before. Furthermore if I run mypy in a standalone fashion I see the following:

> mypy.ini: [mypy]: Unrecognized option: additional_dependencies = [types-requests]

What is the correct way to define additional dependencies in mypy.ini?

Comment: This looks like it should be part of the ``test`` dependencies of the *package*, not some individual tool.

Comment: Thx for the reply but I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Packages can declare optional dependencies. Many packages use this to define a ``test`` dependency target which pulls in everything used to verify the package. Consider the examples for [``setuptools``/``setup.py``](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/90d44abe361688aba5a189e661423863b34f5208/setup.py#L156-L159) or [``flit``](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyproject_toml.html#dependencies).

Comment: Thank you. In this case I'm not building a package so don't have a  setup.py. This python code ultimately gets zipped into a zip file from which we create a GCP Cloud Function (similar to AWS Lambda for anyone familiar with that.)

Comment: @jamiet have you been able to find a solution, please?